# Applying inline-block to divs, but still having weird

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align two divs beside each other using the inline-block technique. My code is fairly simple, but I am not sure why is it not working, I don't know what the issue might be.

Here's my code:

```css
.content .sidebar, .content .section {
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 250px
}
.sidebar {
  background: blue;
}
.section {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="header-area">
    <h3 id="genericpartTitle">Our album</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="sidebar"> hello! </div>
    <div class="section">
      <h5 class="item-title">Welcome to my section</h5>
      <p style="white-space: pre" class="description"> Hello, anything will go here </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Aren't they supposed to be aligned beside each other? what's going wrong here? any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add vertical-align: top; for both sidebar and section classes. checkout the code below.

```css
.content .sidebar, .content .section{
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    min-height: 200px;
    width: 250px
}

.sidebar{
  background: blue;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.section{
  background: red;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="header-area">
        <h3 id="genericpartTitle">Our album</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="sidebar">
           hello!
        </div>

        <div class="section">
            <h5 class="item-title">Welcome to my section</h5>
            <p style="white-space: pre" class="description">
                Hello, anything will go here
            </p>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But why do I need that? Vertical align is for display table right? I know I can do this with just inline-block, but it's not working

Comment: Inline-block css make the elements "Inline-level" elements and for aligning them we need to use vertical align css.

Comment: If you remove the content inside, they will be aligned next to each other, the h5 and p are doing a weird behavior

Comment: not only H5 and P. whatever tag you put inside, it behave weird unless they have the same length content.

Comment: but I added the length for width and height